# How to recognize the variables?

Tags: arrays, lua

I know this is not finished but I can not get to recognize variables. I have 
variables in file x.
sorry it is computercraft im trying to make a turtle go down and keep it's Position and this's is my my first time coding.

```
function getx()
    local rx = fs.open("x", "r")
    local hx = rx:readLine() 
    print(hx)
end

function don()
    getx()
    while hx > 10 do
        ddd()
    end
end

function ddd()
    turtle.down()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your [scoping](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial). Variables defined in one function can't be seen from another.

When `getx` is called, the variable `hx` is only remembered inside of it, there are three ways for you to solve this problem.

### Share the local variable

```lua
local hx;
function getx()
    local rx = fs.open("x", "r")
    hx = rx:readLine()
    print(hx)
end

function don()
    getx()
    while hx > 10 do
        ddd()
    end
end

function ddd()
    turtle.down()
end
```

What's changed here is that `hx` has been declared in the scope that both `don` and `getx` share, so that when `getx` is called, `hx` is stored, and `don` can still access it.

### Globally reference the variable.

```lua
function getx()
    local rx = fs.open("x", "r")
    hx = rx:readLine()
    print(hx)
end

function don()
    getx()
    while hx > 10 do
        ddd()
    end
end

function ddd()
    turtle.down()
end
```

Without declaring `hx` as local, this will use it in the global scope, which all functions can access. Variables that aren't explicitely declares as local will always use this scope.

### Return hx, and use that.

```lua
function getx()
    local rx = fs.open("x", "r")
    local hx = rx:readLine()
    print(hx)
    return hx
end

function don()
    getx()
    while hx > 10 do
        ddd()
    end
end

function ddd()
    turtle.down()
end
```

or better yet...

```lua
function getx()
    local rx = fs.open("x", "r")
    local hx = rx:readLine()
    print(hx)
    return hx
end

function don()
    while getx() > 10 do
        ddd()
    end
end

function ddd()
    turtle.down()
end
```

**This is the solution you should be using for this problem**

By returning the value from your [function](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FunctionsTutorial), you can grab the variable directly from where it's called. This is cleaner, and faster too.

## Avoid your next problem

Your code actually calls `fs.open` every time `getx` is run, as this is [ComputerCraft](http://www.computercraft.info/)'s [FS](http://www.computercraft.info/wiki/Fs_(API)), this will start reading the file from scratch every time, and cause a memory leak, before crashing. To avoid this, you need to open the file only once, like so.

```lua
local rx = fs.open("x", "r")
function getx()
    local hx = rx:readLine()
    print(hx)
    return hx
end

function don()
    while getx() > 10 do
        ddd()
    end
end

function ddd()
    turtle.down()
end
```

This uses the same reference to the file for each calling of `getx`, which means that `readLine()` will read the next line every time.

Some other optimizations you can use, which don't serve much purpose, are below.

```lua
local ddd = turtle.down     -- We don't need to define a new function, we can just make 'ddd' a reference to 'turtle.down'
local rx = fs.open("x", "r")
function don()
    local n = tonumber(rx:readLine())   -- The 'getx' function is not really needed anymore. 'tonumber' will make sure we're handling a number, not a string.
    while n and n > 10 do -- If tonumber doesn't get handed a string that looks like a number, it will return 'nil'. This checks if it's it's nil before seeing if it's greater than 10.
        ddd()
    end
end
```

**Happy crafting!**